# Python for loop iteration

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to fill a dictionary while using loops, problem is the loop stops after fulfilling a condition without checking if there are more available conditions to fulfill,

```
sec=[
     [1, 2, 4.0, 100.0], 
     [2, 3, 1.5, 500.0], 
     [2, 4, 10.0, 700.0], 
     [2, 5, 5.75, 1500.0], 
     [3, 4, 11.4, 200.0], 
     [4, 5, 10.5, 750.0], 
     [4, 6, 6.75, 550.0]]
```

I made this list and there's also this dictionary

`graph={1: [1], 2: [2], 3: [3], 4: [4], 5: [5], 6: [6]}`
what I am trying to accomplish is

```
graph = {1: ['2'],
         2: ['3', '4','5'],
         3: ['4'],
         4: ['5','6'],
         5: [],
         6: []}
```

how it should work is that it collects all `sec[x][0]` as the key of the dictionary and the `sec[n][1]` as the values in the dictionaries 
if sec[x][0] has value 1 and sec[x][1] has the value 2 then number 2 is added to the dictionary as value for key 1
the code I got is this

```
def magic(numList): #turns string into int
   s = ''.join(map(str, numList))
   return int(s)
for i in range(1,len(loc)+1): #len of loc is 6
    for n in range(0,len(loc)+1):
        if magic(graph[i])==sec[n][0]:
            graph[i].append(sec[n][1])
```

but it will only add the first value then index n will stop counting and then index i keeps going and so it will not check for more values in keys

Comment: Hard to tell why the code is not working without knowing what the aptly named `magic` function is doing. Also, are those supposed to be lists of strings?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that, 
def magic(numList): #turns string into int
    s = ''.join(map(str, numList))
    return int(s)
basically turns the string into an int value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial definition of `graph` isn't helpful for the intended result. Initialize the values with empty lists then append in a simple loop:

```
>>> sec=[
     [1, 2, 4.0, 100.0], 
     [2, 3, 1.5, 500.0], 
     [2, 4, 10.0, 700.0], 
     [2, 5, 5.75, 1500.0], 
     [3, 4, 11.4, 200.0], 
     [4, 5, 10.5, 750.0], 
     [4, 6, 6.75, 550.0]]
>>> graph = {i:[] for i in range(1,7)}
>>> for x,y,*z in sec: graph[x].append(str(y))

>>> graph
{1: ['2'], 2: ['3', '4', '5'], 3: ['4'], 4: ['5', '6'], 5: [], 6: []}
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: @roganjosh Maybe, but then you won't have those `[]`.

Comment: Note: `*z` only works in Python 3.x; for older versions, use `for x,y,_,_`

Comment: Thank you @tobias_k I was wondering what the *z meant as a Python 2 user

Answer (score 0):

Use a defaultdict from the collections module. See below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph_dd = defaultdict(list)

for s in sec:
    from_, to_ = s[:2]
    graph_dd[from_].append(to_)
    # do-nothing reference to to_ creates empty list, so that all nodes are represented
    # in graph_dd; else 5 and 6 would not be created
    graph_dd[to_]

# convert to regular dict (not really necessary, but OP wanted a dict)
graph = dict(graph_dd.items())

for k,v in graph.items():
    print(k,':', v)
```

prints:

```
1 : [2]
2 : [3, 4, 5]
3 : [4]
4 : [5, 6]
5 : []
6 : []
```